# Misaka template tags for Django - text wrapped in double quotes

Tags: python, django, markdown

I'd like to replace the standard Markdown implementation in a Django blog I'm building with Github-flavoured Markdown. I'd like to use [Misaka](http://misaka.61924.nl/manual/#toc_13), and I've thrown together my own custom template tags. Unfortunately, something has gone awry.

Here is my template tags file, which is in `blog/templatetags/gfm.py`. The `__init__.py` file is present in the same folder:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import misaka as m

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def gfm(value):
    rendered_text = m.html(value,
                           extensions=m.EXT_FENCED_CODE,
                           render_flags=m.HTML_ESCAPE)
    return rendered_text
```

And here is one of my templates:

```
{% extends 'layout/base.html' %}

{% block header %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% load gfm %}
{% if object_list %}
{% for post in object_list %}

<div class="post">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
    </div>
{{ post.text|gfm }}
<p>Posted {{ post.pub_date }}</p>
<p>
{% for category in post.categories.all %}
    <a class="badge badge-info" href="/category/{{ category.slug }}/">{{ category.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<br />
<ul class="pager">
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
<li class="previous"><a href="/{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}/">Previous Page</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <li class="next"><a href="/{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}/">Next Page</a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<div class="post">
<p>No posts matched</p>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

The outputted text is being returned wrapped in double quotes, which breaks the whole thing. Otherwise, the markup generated seems correct.

Where have I gone wrong here? I know it's not the data in the database as if I use pdb to get the values of `value` and `rendered_text` inside the function, they are rendered correctly. For example, here is the plain text version of one post, as printed by `pdb`:

```
u'A Python application:\r\n\r\n    print "Hello world"'
```

And here is the version rendered in Markdown using Misaka:

```
u'<p>A Python application:</p>\n\n<pre><code>print &quot;Hello world&quot;\n</code></pre>\n'
```

I'm fairly experienced with Django, but I'm new to custom template tags.

Comment: What is the input and do you have CSS or Python double quotes?

Comment: @pxl Have added the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) tag.

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ post.text|gfm }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Alternatively you can use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter.

```
{{ post.text|gfm|safe }}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's resolved it. I'm actually going to go back and dump the custom template tag in favour of rendering the text as a separate field when the model is saved so it's not rendering as Markdown every time the page loads, but the same princinple should apply.